# Convert difference of dates to date with timestamp

Tags: oracle, plsql

How to convert the difference of 2 dates with a timestamp to date with timestamp again, Oracle giving number but i want to compare timestamp.

```
select emp_date>to_date(sysdate,'yyyy-MM-dd HH24:MI:SS')-todate('2021-03-22 10:20:12') from emp;
```

above query giving error: expected date but got NUMBER.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is the data type of `emp_date`? Assuming that it is a `DATE` data type, how do you expect to compare a `date` to a interval between two other dates? What does it even mean to say `DATE '2021-03-22' > INTERVAL '1 02:34:56' DAY TO SECOND'`?

Comment: Ignoring your code, please can you explain (in English) the problem that you are trying to solve? You have an XY-problem in this question and you are down a rabbit hole trying to make the code you have work when it fundamentally is not going to. I think you need to take a step back and [edit] your question to explain what the root problem is and what data your table contains and what your expected output is (give us a [MRE]).

Answer (score 0):

What you are saying makes no sense. Difference of two `DATE` datatype values is **number of days** between them. For example

```
SQL> select sysdate - to_date('21.03.2021 13:12', 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi') diff from dual;

      DIFF
----------
,943217593

SQL>
```

You CAN convert it to a prettier format (days, hours, minutes, seconds), but it is still a NUMBER, it is not a date.

Therefore, you can't compare `EMP_DATE` (which is a `DATE` datatype column, isn't it?) to a number as it just doesn't make sense.

Is 22nd of March 2021 larger or smaller than 0.94? It's neither.

Comment: emp_date is date , yeah i know i am getting error , so you are saying there is no way to comapre?

Comment: that is the reason my question is how to convert this number again to date so i can compare?

Comment: It seems you don't understand what I'm saying. How can you compare 22.03.2021 (today's date) with 25? What do you expect to get out of such a comparison? It is as if you compare apple to oxygen, it is just useless, they can't be compared.

Comment: i know we cant compare thats why i am seeing error , is it possible to get minutes and seconds from sysdate and compare?

Comment: Compare to what?

Comment: select * from emp where emp_date>(sysdate-2/1440) , this query is working correctly .Giving last 2 minutes updates from emp table.

Comment: Yes, it works because you are comparing two DATE datatype values.

Comment: similarly is it not possible subtract hours,minutes and seconds from sysdate ,so i can compare with date?

Comment: It is possible to subtract hours etc. from dates - you already did that ("sysdate - 2/1440"), didn't you?

Answer (score 0):

[TL;DR] You cannot as your data types do not match and it does not make sense to compare a date/time value to an interval.

---

If you do:

```sql
date_value1 - date_value2
```

You will get a `NUMBER` data type representing the number of (fractional) days between the two date values.

You can explicitly cast the subtraction operation to get an `INTERVAL DAY TO SECOND` data type using:

```sql
(date_value1 - date_value2) DAY TO SECOND
```

So, for your code that would be:

```sql
SELECT emp_date > ( sysdate - TO_DATE( '2021-03-22 10:20:12', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS' ) ) DAY TO SECOND
FROM   emp;
```

However, that will fail as you cannot compare a `DATE` to an `INTERVAL DAY TO SECOND` and SQL does not have a boolean data type so `>` does not make sense.

To fix that later point you could use a `CASE` expression but the difference in data types is a show-stopper as you can't compare a date to an interval.

> but i want to compare timestamp.

You don't have a `TIMESTAMP` data type, you have either a number (representing an interval in days) or an `INTERVAL` data type. If you want to convert it back to a `DATE` or `TIMESTAMP` then you need to add your interval to an epoch value.

Comment: ok , how to convert that number to date so i can compare with date, is it possible?

Comment: @user914357 Please explain to me in English, how you expect to convert 1 day, 4 hours, 23 minutes and 15 seconds to a date such as 2021-03-22T09:53:42? The question does not make sense as a date is an instant in time and an interval is a duration and you cannot convert from one to the other. You can add an interval to a date (that epoch I mentioned) to get another date but you cannot just convert an interval to a date.

Comment: :) i know we cant compare thats why i am seeing error , is it possible to get minutes and seconds from sysdate and compare? orelse tell me any other way its possible to compare?

Comment: @user914357 As I said in a comment on your question, edit the question to give us a [MRE] to explain the problem you are trying to solve (and not just some code that you want fixed). Your code will not work on a fundamental level as you are trying to compare two things that cannot be compared and you have not given details of the problem so we cannot help with the wider scope as your question only gives us a very narrow view of what you are trying to do.

Comment: select * from emp where emp_date>(sysdate-2/1440) , this query is working correctly .Giving last 2 minutes results from emp table.

Comment: Of course it works, as you compare two DATE datatype values.

Comment: @user914357 In that last comment, you are comparing a `DATE` to a `DATE - NUMBER` where the number represents an interval and if you evaluate the right-hand side you get a `DATE` so you are comparing have equal types. Yes, that works. However, I am not seeing what that has to do with your code as you have not given any context to why you brought up that snippet of code. Please stop just giving us random pieces of code and give us the context of the problem (an English description please, not code); if you do that then we will know what you are trying to achieve and may be able to help.

Comment: similarly is it not possible subtract hours,minutes and seconds from sysdate ,so i can compare with date?

Comment: @user914357 `SELECT * FROM emp WHERE emp_date > SYSDATE - INTERVAL '01:23:45' HOUR TO SECOND;` Is that what you are after? [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=78b424c4c01107539f4807efda29a1e1)